# Strlen into a structure

Tags: structure, strlen

Hello i am trying to use a strlen function in an structure but i am failing badly.
My code is this:
after the scanf i get only the first caracter of the table and in the last print f the programm crashes.
Any suggestions or ideas what i am doing wrong?
Mainly the user will fill the table with alphanumerics and with the strlen i would like to extract the lenght of the alphanumerics.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(void)
{
int M,N;

struct word_pair /*structure  */
    {
    char word[M]; // the alphanumeric
    int lenght; //the lenght of alphanumeric
    };
struct word_pair word_table[N]; // the table of alphanumeric and lenght

printf("Enter a frase:");
 scanf("%c",&word_table[N].word[M]);
 printf("\n Your frase is %c ",word_table[N].word[M]);
printf("\n %u ",(unsigned)strlen(word_table[N].word[M]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare an array of `word_pair` of but you use only one `struct` in the array and you store it in an invalid position(`N`). Take into account that when you declare an array of length `n` such as `int a[n];` the valid positions inside the array are from `0` to `n - 1`.

You must first initialize the variables `N` and `M` to whatever value you need. After that, try (assuming that `N > 0` and `M > 0`):

```
scanf("%c",&word_table[0].word[0]);
printf("\n Your frase is %c ",word_table[0].word[0]);
printf("\n %u ",(unsigned)strlen(word_table[0].word[0]));
```